# How can a Command(derived from a ICommand) access a viewmodel 

Tags: wpf, mvvm, model

I have a Command - AddCommand , which has to add the users to the database.
The business logic to add to database is in the ViewModel methods (Add_to_Db, Delete_from_Db).
But i need the command(AddCommand) to acces the viewmodel(for all the methods) without passing the viewmodel as CommandParameter from XAML.

As i need to pass other info(UserInfo) as CommandParameter to the command.
What are the ways a command can have access to the related ViewModel.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding your question, but shouldn't the RelayCommand be a property of the ViewModel? In other words, it should already have access to the ViewModel, where you can maintain some state like your UserInfo.

Comment: I am not using RelayCommand but using a normal command.So methods from ViewModel cannot be passed to command ( compared to command constructor in Relay Command) when the command is created in the view model.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DelegateCommand`.

References:

[MVVM Infrastructure: DelegateCommand](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/04/mvvm-infrastructure-delegatecommand.html)

[How to implement a reusable ICommand](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html)

All you do is pass a method of you `ViewModel` class to this `DelegateCommand` that gets executed when command is executed. That way you can access your `ViewModel`. And it's reusable and widely used approach, too.

Comment: If i dont want to use DelegateCommand ( which basically takes any method) then what is the way to access the view Model.

Comment: If not delegate command, what type of implementation would you use? Post an example and I could suggest other ways.

Comment: I agree Delegate Command is simpler.But I just wanted to use a command ( derived from ICommand) for various operations like add,delete,modify data based on user actions(button click) and then do business operations(eg.add/delete/modify) using appropriate methods(add/delete/modify) of ViewModel in the execute() methods of respective Commands(add/delete).But how do i access these methods(add/delete) of viewmodels in the execute() method of command.  => 1 way is to pass viewmodel object as CommandParamter.What are the otherways to access viewmodel object from the execute() method of commands.